# VS Code Add New Font HTML

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code, fonts, new-operator

I want to know how to add a new font to VS Code, so I can set the font family to that specific font. (I want the text on the website to appear in that font)

I am new to HTML and CSS.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face

Answer (score 0):

To set the new font in Visual studio code follow the path given below:

**Open VSCode -> Go to File option -> Preference -> Setting**

You will come Here

[image]

There is a Font Family option where you can put your font name which you want.

**To get the font's you can go to *[Google fonts](https://fonts.google.com/)* for a huge number of collections.**

This font cannot get reflected on your website as it is restricted for VSCode only.
But to use different fonts on the website or application you can use
**HTML link** tag or you can download on your folder and use it.

For example,

Firstly, **Select your Favourite font from google fonts.**

[image]

You can download it or use as link in html file.

`<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">`

[image]

You can use more than one font for your project.

*All the very best for your HTML and CSS journey.*

Answer (score -1):

You can do that in 3 steps easily.

**Step 1** - Download the required font (to get free and really good fonts is [Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/))

**Step 2** - Install the downloaded font

**Step 3** - Using Font settings in VS Code, you have change it as below.

- In your VS code editor **Go to File > Preferences > settings** and search font.
- Insert the name of the newly downloaded font
- need to restart your PC before the changes take effect